# Excel pivot table filter in Python via win32com

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I tried really hard to find how to do these simple lines of VBA code in Python via win32com but I couldn't find how to execute it properly :

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Quarters").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Effective deadline"). _
    PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlBefore, Value1:="10/10/2017"
```

When running these lines :

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx

excel = DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('MySheet')
ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Quarters").PivotFilters('Add2', 'xlBefore', '10/10/2017')
```

I end up with an 'Invalid number of parameters' so I guess I'm quite close but can't find the documentation to complete my code

Has anyone ever managed to do this kind of work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the wrong method. You should call `.Add2` after the `PivotFilters` property:

```
ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Effective deadline").ClearAllFilters()
ws.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Effective deadline").PivotFilters.Add2(31, None, '10/10/2017')
```

Also, notice that you need to specify the [XlPivotFilterType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpivotfiltertype-enumeration-excel) according to the type of filter you want to apply (in this case `xlBefore` = `31`)

Comment: You're a true lifesaver ! Thanks for the link it will definitely be useful to me in the future